# How to import jdcal in python

Tags: python, import

I have installed `jdcal` in `python`, when I ask a list of installed packages jdcal is in the list:

```
*['**jdcal==1.2**', 'numpy==1.11.1', 'openpyxl==2.4.0', 'pandas==0.18.1', 'pip==8.1.1', 'python-dateutil==2.5.3', 'pytz==2016.6.1', 'setuptools==20.10.1', 'six==1.10.0']*
```

But when I want to import `jdcal`, I get an `import-error`:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/TEMP/test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import jdcal
**ImportError: No module named 'jdcal'***
```

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.